# Is this possible to use SOCKS proxy in App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, proxy

Have to build some kind of cloud-hosted crawler application and wondering whether  GAE supports proxying requests through SOCKS proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. GAE's sandbox is restricted in this matter, so you won't be able to use SOCKS/HTTP proxy in your GAE-based application.